# Excel VBA to Export from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: vba, excel

I am running the code below and it skips every other field when exporting data from Excel to SQL Server.  This is very weird.  Maybe something is off with the incrementer, but I can't tell what it is.  Can someone shed some light on this?  Thanks.

```
Sub testexportsql()
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ServerName As String
    Dim DatabaseName As String
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim UserID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim RowCounter As Long
    Dim NoOfFields As Integer
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim ColCounter As Integer

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ServerName = "server_name" ' Enter your server name here
    DatabaseName = "db_name" ' Enter your  database name here
    TableName = "customer_master" ' Enter your Table name here
    UserID = "" ' Enter your user ID here
    ' (Leave ID and Password blank if using windows Authentification")
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    NoOfFields = 331 ' Enter number of fields to update (eg. columns in your worksheet)
    StartRow = 2 ' Enter row in sheet to start reading  records
    EndRow = 106695 ' Enter row of last record in sheet

     '  CHANGES
    Dim shtSheetToWork As Worksheet
    Set shtSheetToWork = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("customer_master")
     '********

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
    ";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open TableName, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

     'EndRow = shtSheetToWork.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For RowCounter = StartRow To EndRow
        rs.AddNew
        For ColCounter = 1 To NoOfFields
        'On Error Resume Next
            rs(ColCounter - 1) = shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, ColCounter)
            ColCounter = ColCounter + 1
        Next ColCounter
        Debug.Print RowCounter
    Next RowCounter
    rs.UpdateBatch

     ' Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, it is in your code. The For...Next loop does the incrementing job by itself, and you are "dubbing" it by additionally incrementing the loop variable. Simply remove the line

```
 ColCounter = ColCounter + 1
```